# Swift/iOS best practice for laying out screen elements

Tags: ios, swift

I have been trying to find some advice on the best practice method of laying out screen elements in my swift project. I've found a number of posts that tell me where I can lay things out, but I am keen to find out what whether my approach is correct / acceptable or not.

A few of my apps have reasonably complex layouts, e.g. the one I'm working on now has a `UITabViewController` with the first tab including a `UINavigationViewController`, and the navigation view containing a `UIPageViewController`. Due to having a range of issues with correctly displaying screen elements (e.g. elements appearing behind other elements, elements appearing with the incorrect screen sizes etc), I now do the following:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
    self.view.addSubview(firstSubview)
    self.view.addSubview(secondSubview)
}
```

Then I setup each view in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` like so:

```
func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    self.firstSubview.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)
    self.secondSubview.frame = CGRectMake(x, z, w, h)
}
```

This works perfectly from what I can see, and I've only ended up here after having issues with sizing, and element order (is it called hierarchy?).

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be clear: The code you've posted does work, without error, you're just asking if you should be doing it this way?

Comment: Correct, the code above is just an example of the way in which I do it. The code I am using works fine but I have a niggly feeling that it's just not a good way to do it. Although, I could be wrong and this may be an acceptable way to do it. The question really relates to "Should I add my subviews in viewDidLoad, and then setup the frames / properties of the subviews in viewWillLayoutSubviews / viewDidLayoutSubviews".

Comment: This is likely to result in opinion based answers. Can you reword your question so that there's an objective measure of comparison? (For example "better" could mean "less code")

Comment: I figure there must be a best practice for this though and that's what my question title refers to. Can you tell me how you lay out your subviews as an example?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on when you want your layout code to happen.

For basic layouts, you should initialize views and add subviews in viewDidLoad. And for frame changes, it can be viewDidLayoutSubviews, viewWillLayoutSubviews. You can also use viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear when you want to reload some views (such as updating text after dismissing a presented view controller).